# How do I open Ubuntu Software Center via Terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-center

I am a newbie in linux and I don't know how to open the Ubuntu Software Center via Terminal!!
Please help

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure why you'd want to, but

```
software-center
```

should do it.  If you want to use command line to install a package then the correct way to do it would be

```
sudo apt-get install package-name
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove package-name
```

to remove it.  If you want a text based package manager then you could have a look at aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude
```

Comment: Want to do it because all of the searches for Software Center say to click the Ubuntu icon. But there is no such icon. Some say the Software Center is in the Launcher but where the heck is that? Your "software-center" method just yields "software-center: command not found"

Comment: if you are running Ubuntu under WLS (WIndows) and an X-server, you are probably not running the desktop, hence want to run the tool directly.

Comment: `E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Ubuntu 21.10. It doesn't launch Ubuntu Software, it says command not found.

Answer (score 29):

For Gnome Software replacing the old Canonical Ubuntu Software Centre <`software-centre`> (Preinstalled on Ubuntu 16.04 and later)

Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Then run;

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
gnome-software
```

For the the official gui software store `snap-store`;

First make sure `snapd` is installed and enabled

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Then install Snap Store

```
sudo snap install snap-store
snap-store
```

You can also replace the stable version with the preview version by running;

```
sudo snap remove snap-store && sudo snap install snap-store --channel=preview/edge
```

To revert back to the stable build of Snap Store run;

```
sudo snap remove snap-store && sudo snap install snap-store --stable
```

Comment: which might require a preliminary 'sudo apt-get install gnome-software'

Comment: in my WSL (windows) ubuntu, this launches something, but it I'm getting lots of errors e.g., `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast` etc. The GUI comes up, but there is no software listed as installed.

Comment: This is not the "Ubuntu Software" app that installs snaps that ships by default in Ubuntu 21.10. Instead, it will give you a "command not found" error.

Answer (score 10):

You simply enter the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and write:

```
ubuntu-software
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: That just gives "software-center: command not found"

Comment: In Ubuntu 21.10, this answer doesn't work. It gives a "command not found" error. Ubuntu 21.10 doesn't ship with either `ubuntu-software` or `software-center`

Answer (score 10):

Times have changed, and with them, the answer to this question. In desktop Ubuntu 21.04, it is still possible to install Ubuntu Software Center. Since that is the program specified by the original question, the answer is that you run it from the command line, first by [installing it](https://www.maketecheasier.com/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-fixes/) via:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

and then by running it via the following command, [with or without](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271425/software-updates-requires-sudo-on-ubuntu20-04) `sudo`:

```
gnome-software
```

You can also run it by using *Show Applications* → *Software* icon (white suitcase with aqua circle).

Since Ubuntu Software Center is no longer installed by default, this question (if asked today) would refer, instead, to the Snap Store. If it was not present, it would [reportedly](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-the-official-snap-store-app-on-linux/) be installed via:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

In that case, the answer is that you run it via

```
snap-store
```

Or you could click on the suitcase icon, in this case an orange one bearing the letter A (short for "Snap" in Latin, perhaps), whose tool tip says (of course) "Ubuntu Software".

Comment: This worked in Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 3):

I use the snap-store and don't usually have an issue.

```
snap-store
```

Comment: This worked for me, but as soon as I click on an app I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: The SegFault might be GPU driver related. I used a nvidia-driver and switched to x.org nouveau-driver and it works now

Answer (score 0):

For me following worked:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04.3 use the command

```
snap-store
```

In case it does not load try this:

```
killall snap-store
sudo snap refresh
```

**source:** [Ubuntu software does not load in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+question/707874)