# How to open the Software-Center in the terminal?

Tags: 12.04

I'm new at this Ubuntu stuff and I'm trying to get the software center but every time I put in the command in the terminal it is just saying package not found.

I am 100% sure that I have been putting in the command right. Can any one help with where I am supposed to get this package?

Comment: Are you trying to *open* the software center or *install* it? In both cases: what command did you use and what exactly was the output?

Comment: Katrina, could you clarify your question? install or open? The title is edited, but is it correct?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Software center wasn't installed initially and hence couldn't be opened

Comment: @RohithMadhavan why do you think it wasn't installed?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think OP must have removed it by mistake

Comment: @RohithMadhavan never mind, I see it in the history below your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open Ubuntu Software Center via Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231695/how-do-i-open-ubuntu-software-center-via-terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to open the software center via the Terminal is -

`software-center`

Additionally, if you wish to display a package using the software center -

`software-center <packagename>`

To install it -

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

Comment: so what exactly do i need to type into the terminal

Comment: `software-center`

Comment: it said command not found

Comment: Install it using `sudo apt-get install software-center`

Comment: omg thank you that has cleared everything up thank you so much

Comment: @KatrinaPurvis Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you with your problem!