# Software & Updates requires sudo on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: gnome, permissions, software-center

I am setting up a new machine with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed. I'm having a strange issue where I can't access Software & Updates through "Ubuntu Software."

I tried opening it from the command line (`gnome-software`) but it does not show up as an option under the dropdown on the top-right of the application.

However, when I run `sudo gnome-software` from the command line, the option is there and I can access Softwate & Updates from the dropdown.

I checked my account with `groups <uname>` and I am listed as part of both the admin and sudo groups.

How do I set things up that I can access Software & Updates without explicitly requiring a `sudo` command in the terminal? On my other machine, which is still running 18.04, I have full access through the GUI with no problems. Is this a change with 20.04 or is there some setting I can change in my user account?

Comment: You have a strange issue. When I click the Software & Updates icon in the Dash in Ubuntu 20.04 it opens immediately with no authentication required.

Comment: @karel: I don't have that experience :-/. I guess it's not a 20.04 thing. Perhaps a user accounts issue?

Comment: There is a bug in the Ubuntu 20.04 installer that when you make an error and click the back button and correct the error it saves the incorrect settings anyway without changing them even though you corrected the error. If that happened to you check if your settings are correct.