# how to open "Ubuntu Software" on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, software-center

first off: I am aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231695/how-do-i-open-ubuntu-software-center-via-terminal)

I want to open the "Ubuntu Software"
I do have it installed, because I can see and open it from my menu-bar

[picture of "Ubuntu Software" in menu-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcC0b.png)

I want to open it with the Terminal, because when I try to install "Dropbox" from Ubuntu Software, it just closes automatically. And now I want to see, if it works when I start it from the terminal.

I've tried all of these:

```
:~$ software-center
software-center: command not found

:~$ gnome-software
Command 'gnome-software' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gnome-software

:~$ ubuntu-software
ubuntu-software: command not found
```

what else could I try?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on 64-bit, with GNOME Version 3.36.8

Comment: What happens when you click on the icon for Software?

Comment: it opens, just as it should..
but then when going on the dropbox icon it just shuts down

Comment: Did you try any other items other then dropbox?

Comment: yes I did, and all of the ones I've tried worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `snap-store`. That will launch the default Ubuntu software center, provided it is installed on your system (provided it is installed).

If it is not (anymore) installed, you can install it with the command `sudo snap install snap-store`.

Comment: thanks, thats what I wanted.
Now it actually worked (: